# Junit test for a output in console

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Still I couldn't find the reason to fail the test method for following method.

```
public static void print() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

My Junit test method is as follows

```
@Test
public void testPrint(){
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

   PrintStream old = System.out;

   System.setOut(ps);

   //execute the above method
   obj.print();

   System.out.flush();
   System.setOut(old);

   //test method
   String expected = "hello" + "\n";
   assertEquals(expected, baos.toString());
}
```

AssertionFailed Error was expected: `<hello but was <hello>`

So the issue should be with the newline character. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing test like that is nice place to use mock:

```java
// code with Mockito
@Test
public void testPrint(){
  PrintStream mockedPrintStream = Mockito.mock(PrintStream.class);
  PrintStream old = System.out;
  System.setOut(mockedPrintStream);

  obj.print();

  Mockito.verify(mockedPrintStream).println("hello");

  System.setOut(old); // add this line when edit
}
```

Now you check is method called with param.

More about mocking in [Mockito manual](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1)

---

Edit – answer to question from comment

`PrintStream old = System.out;` you need this line because in `System.out` is en external code and after test you should clean up state of all objects that you contaminate during test.

In most cases this cleaning happens in `@TearDown` method or just because obejcts were deleted by GC when `@Test` method return.

In this case you need to do that manually and in the test method, because there are no other place where you can restore state of `System.out` property to the state before test.

Comment: Ok I did it. And the `PrintStream old = System.out;` in above is not needed right?